# How to change package name of an android project in all the branches?

Tags: android, git

I know how to change the package name of an existing android project. But how can one do this for all the branches, especially since different branches have appreciable differences in their file sets?

Answer (score 0):

I think! it is not possible to do the same in all branches you must merge all the branch into master once then do the same and the split again there is no other procedure to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be to push changes to one branch, and then cherry pick it to other branches

Comment: File sets are different so cherry pick will not work.

Comment: well, then you can always checkout each of the branches and then change package name and push it again to that branch, but that could be a lot of work.
You might consider deleting branches that you don't need, and merge the ones that you can merge together. Other than that, I believe there isn't a way